# handling backbone model/collection changes in react.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, reactjs

I've been working with facebooks framework React.js together with Backbone for the last couple of weeks and I'm still not entirely sure what is the most appropriate way to re-render a React component when there are changes in a Backbone collection that has been passed in as a prop.

currently what I do is in `componenentWillMount` I set up `change/add/remove` listeners on the collection and set state when it triggers:

```
componentWillMount: function(){
    var myCollection = this.props.myCollection;
    var updateState = function(){
        this.setState({myCollection: myCollection.models});
    }

    myCollections.on("add remove", updateState, this);
    updateState();
}

render: function(){
    var listItems = this.state.myCollection.map(function(item){
        return <li>{item.get("someAttr")}</li>;
    });
    return <ul>{listItems}</ul>;
}
```

I have seen examples where the models are cloned to the state:

```
var updateState = function () {
    this.setState({ myCollection: _.clone(this.myCollection.models) });
};
```

I've also seen variants where model/collection in props is used directly in render instead of using state, and then forceUpdate is called when the collections/model changes, causing the component to re-render

```
componentWillMount: function(){
    var myCollection = this.props.myCollection;
    myCollections.on("add remove", this.forceUpdate, this);
}

render: function(){
    var listItems = this.props.myCollection.map(function(item){
        return <li>{item.get("someAttr")}</li>;
    });
    return <ul>{listItems}</ul>;
}
```

what benefits and drawbacks are there to the different approaches?
Is there a way of doing it that is **The React way**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of manually binding event listeners, you can use a mixin based on this BackboneMixin to help automatically bind and unbind the listeners:

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/1be9a9e/examples/todomvc-backbone/js/app.js#L148-L171

Then you simply write

```
var List = React.createClass({
    mixins: [BackboneMixin],

    getBackboneModels: function() {
        return [this.props.myCollection];
    },

    render: function(){
        var listItems = this.props.myCollection.map(function(item){
            return <li>{item.get("someAttr")}</li>;
        });
        return <ul>{listItems}</ul>;
    }
});
```

and the component will be rerendered when anything changes in the collection. You only need to put BackboneMixin on the top-level component -- any descendants will be rerendered automatically at the same time.

Comment: Note that with the linked implementation of BackboneMixin, getBackboneModels must always return the same list of models. If getBackboneModels changes to return different objects then the event handlers won't be properly bound and unbound. If this is a problem for you it's not hard to make BackboneMixin a bit smarter.

Comment: Since Backbone Model events are passed to the containing Collection, the Mixin should be changed a bit to listen to the Collection. I ended up with: `componentDidMount: function() {
      this._boundForceUpdate = this.forceUpdate.bind(this, null);
      this.getBackboneObject().on("all", this._boundForceUpdate, this);
    },`

Comment: Re: putting it only in the top-level component, if in a child component I need to slice the collection or create another subset of it of something, am I correct to assume that the subset/sliced collection will require another instantiation of the mixin ? thanks.

Answer (score 10):

IMO, React is still very new and there are very few established rules on how to work with data and reactive models like Backbone. This is also a strength, if you have an existing application - react can be integrated on some smaller parts of it without redefining the entire data flow.

I believe that since React can call render "smart" at any time – that is only re-rendering parts that have changed – you don’t really need to pass data as states. Just pass the data, add listeners on the top component and call `forceUpdate` when the model has changed and it will propagate down nicely.

It just seems more "right" to pass backbone models as props, not states.

One important thing that I learned the hard way is to use the `model.cid` as key (and not `Math.random()`) when rendering backbone model lists:

```
var listItems = this.props.myCollection.map(function(item){
    return <li key={item.cid}>{item.get("someAttr")}</li>;
});
```

Because otherwise React won’t be able to recognize what model to re-render because all of them will have new keys on each render.

Comment: I like that this way is a bit more concise than adding the collection to state, but on the other hand it's a bit more clear if anything that changes (e.g. a collection) is inside of state, since the it's the STATE of the collection you are interested in when you render.
I'm still a bit torn as to which is the preferable way.

Answer (score 5):

I had been playing around with the BackboneMixin mentioned here and a couple other react resources (of the limited info currently out there). I found that when I was listening to a collection that was being updated from the server, just as many n 'add' events are going to be triggered on the collection and listened to by the BackboneMixin, thus calling force update n number of times, which calls render and whatever is called from render n number of times.

Instead, I used underscore/lo-dash's throttle method to limit the number of times forceUpdate would be called. At the very least this has limited the render method from being called so much. I know react isn't actually doing any DOM manipulation there, and its just a virtual DOM, but still there is no reason it should be called 100 times for 100 immediate additions to a Collection.

So my solution looks like https://gist.github.com/ssorallen/7883081 but with the componentDidMount method like this instead:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  //forceUpdate will be called at most once every second
  this._boundForceUpdate = _.throttle(this.forceUpdate.bind(this, null), 1000);
  this.getBackboneObject().on("all", this._boundForceUpdate, this);
}
```

Comment: This is the one I'm currently using. It's not entirely clear how I'd handle events with more granularity. But I guess I could rely on binging `listenTo` and such on `getInitialState`...

Answer (score 1):

There's another BackboneMixin, [courtesy of Eldar Djafarov](http://eldar.djafarov.com/2013/11/reactjs-mixing-with-backbone/), that re-renders your component when the model changes and also provides a very convenient way to get two-way databinding:

```
  var BackboneMixin = {
    /* Forces an update when the underlying Backbone model instance has
     * changed. Users will have to implement getBackboneModels().
     * Also requires that React is loaded with addons.
     */
    __syncedModels: [],
    componentDidMount: function() {
      // Whenever there may be a change in the Backbone data, trigger a reconcile.
      this.getBackboneModels().forEach(this.injectModel, this);
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
      // Ensure that we clean up any dangling references when the component is
      // destroyed.
      this.__syncedModels.forEach(function(model) {
        model.off(null, model.__updater, this);
      }, this);
    },
    injectModel: function(model){
      if(!~this.__syncedModels.indexOf(model)){
        var updater = this.forceUpdate.bind(this, null);
        model.__updater = updater;
        model.on('add change remove', updater, this);
      }
    },
    bindTo: function(model, key){
      /* Allows for two-way databinding for Backbone models.
       * Use by passing it as a 'valueLink' property, e.g.:
       *   valueLink={this.bindTo(model, attribute)} */
      return {
        value: model.get(key),
        requestChange: function(value){
            model.set(key, value);
        }.bind(this)
      };
    }
  }
```

Here's his jsFiddle that demonstrates the usage:
http://jsfiddle.net/djkojb/qZf48/13/

Comment: Can someone explain how model gets added to __syncedModels? Or is there a bug and it isn't?

Comment: @Tom check the fiddle, in your custom component you should define getBackboneModels which will return models that will go into __syncedModels

Comment: I understand what is supposed to happen, I just can't follow how the return value from `getBackboneModels` gets added into `__syncedModels` in the mixin: it must be missing a line - `this.__syncedModels.push(model);` right?

Comment: I.e. The fiddle works, and so would other simple uses, but the `__syncedModels` guard is not actually working so if `getBackboneModels` returned the same model instance more than once, the `forceUpdate` would get fired multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

[react.backbone](https://github.com/clayallsopp/react.backbone) seems to be the most recent solution for React-Backbone integration. Haven't tested it yet though.