# how to use setProps in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I want to call `setProps` from outside of `myComponent` to be able to dynamically change data for `myComponent`.
I expect that after changing props of the component, it will re-render itself.

I was trying the following:

```jsx
var myComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      React.DOM.div(null, this.props.data)
    );
  }
});

React.renderComponent(
  myComponent({ data: someData }),
  document.getElementById('predictionContent')
);

myComponent.setProps({data: someData2});
```

The problem is that I don't understand how to use `setProps` for the component.
In my case, I receive "undefined" error.

How to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass new server data to react.js components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20605309/pass-new-server-data-to-react-js-components)

Comment: Side note: myComponent is the component class.  The only place setProps works is on a component instance, which you can only get either with `this` inside one of the component's methods or with `this.refs` from the component rendering it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**warning:** `setProps` is [now deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#new-deprecations-introduced-with-a-warning).

`React.createClass` returns a class, it is `React.renderComponent` which returns an instance of the class which has the `setProps` method.

Try this instead:

```jsx
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return React.DOM.div(null, this.props.data);
    }
});

var myComponent = React.renderComponent(
     new MyComponent({ data: someData }),
     document.getElementById('predictionContent')
);

myComponent.setProps({ data: someData2 });
```

Having said that, Chad Scira's answer is also correct: probably better to re-render than to call setProps. That will keep it looking the same as the code inside the render() method, and you'll always be able to call `renderComponent`, regardless of whether it is the first time or a subsequent update.

Like this:

```jsx
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return React.DOM.div(null, this.props.data);
    }
});

React.renderComponent(
     new MyComponent({ data: someData }),
     document.getElementById('predictionContent')
);

// later
React.renderComponent(
     new MyComponent({ data: someData2 }),
     document.getElementById('predictionContent')
);
```

Comment: Kudos for suggesting the component re-render. This helped me out a ton.

Answer (score 10):

You're not supposed to do that. Instead just run the renderComponent method again like this:

```jsx
React.renderComponent(
     myComponent({ data: someData2 }),
     document.getElementById('predictionContent')
);
```

react will automatically resolve the differences

Comment: Then why do we have setProps function if it is not possible to change props from outside of the component?

Comment: @31415926 see [the setProps docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setprops); they try to discourage it (for good reason).  It's mostly a relic of early react versions.