# Backbone model force update with nested react components

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, reactjs

I've been using Backbone to manage my models, and react to render views on model changes.

To do so I've used the accepted answer here: [handling backbone model/collection changes in react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371566/handling-backbone-model-collection-changes-in-react-js) wherein the provided mixin listens for updates on the model/collection and simply calls forceUpdate on the component.

This works great for the first root component where the mixin is used. However, for nested components inside which solely rely on the model attributes, those will never get updated since react loses old/new state as mentioned by Pete Hunt (core React developer) here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/reactjs/lT2pOKXUHY8/_mahBiK2ZxMJ

I see two solutions to this:

1. Use a json version of the model or collection after the root component for all following children components. (Pass along model={this.props.model.attributes} to the children)
2. use the mixin in for the children components as well via a global model/collection

option 1 seems to limit backbone's power as now only attributes flow through the chain and other methods on the model are lost.
option 2 seems like an anti-pattern in general when the mixin was developed. Plus you need to keep track of the global and update the bindings for the children as well.

Am I missing something or is there a simpler solution to this problem?

Comment: You could use the mixin in child components without globals; simply pass the models themselves down through properties.

Comment: **Option 1** is better, lose the mixin. Hiding backbone's features from the children keeps your components simple, and you aren't tied to backbone's way of doing things in the future. I'd consider keeping the model outside of all the components, only passing raw data. Then, on change events, setProps on the root component to trigger an update.

Comment: @BrandonTilley In that case I would still have to keep track of when the model changes myself since its updates are outside of React components and redo bindings on every willReceiveProps for the children.

Comment: @Shawn I understand that's a cleaner solution, but the components at this stage are heavily nested and depend on various model/collection properties and methods, cleaning that up would be quite a task I'm afraid.